# Making custom settings data visible in test classes

Tags: code-coverage, customsetting

I am trying to add custom settings data into my Test DataFactory so as to increase test coverage.

I currently create data for custom settings in my test datafactory.This is both time consuming and tedious to maintain.

Here is how a simplified version of the datafactory

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
public class Test_DataFactory {

public static void createMyAppCustomSettings() {
        List<MyAppCustomSettings__c> applst = new List<MyAppCustomSettings__c>();
        applst.add(new MyAppCustomSettings__c(Name = 'Test 1'));
        applst.add(new MyAppCustomSettings__c(Name = 'Test 2'));
        Database.insert(applst,true);
  }

}
```

Then i call the `createMyAppCustomSettings()` method in  `testSetup` in a test class.How can i add make `MyAppCustomSettings__c` without me having to create the data manually.

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
private class Test_MyAppCustomSettings {
    @testSetup
    static void buildTestClassData() {
       Test_DataFactory.createMyAppCustomSettings();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're meant to insert Custom Settings during a unit test (at least, with isolation enabled). You *should* choose to insert custom settings when testing code that depends on those custom settings. If you really want to use existing settings, you can use `SeeAllData=true`, but this is *not* recommended. Do not do it. Insert your Custom Settings as you're meant to do.

Comment: Is there a way i can make only the data for the custom settings only visible.I already tried adding SeeAllData=true in the testdatafactory but i still wasn't getting the records

Comment: @user2650277 You need to use SeeAllData=true on the *class* where the test runs. A utility class can't specify their own isolation.

Comment: Ohh but if i do that for the Test_MyAppCustomSettings  , then all data for the org will be visible.Is there a way to write the `Test_MyAppCustomSettings` in such a way that only  MyAppCustomSettings__c  is visible

Comment: @user2650277 Nope. It's all or nothing. The official recommendation is to insert any custom settings that you need.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm seems to be a better option.What do you think

Comment: @user2650277 If you use "testSetup", you'll get much better performance. Yes, you can use static resources, but it still requires isolation and loading the records each class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78686/discussion-between-user2650277-and-sfdcfox).

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom metadata types instead of custom setting, it behaves same as custom settings and it is also available in test classes without using **seealldata=true**  annonation

here is the salesforce trailhead link for the it describing same https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/custom_metadata_types/units/custom_metadata_types_create#

Comment: That's partially true. Custom Metadata Types are often less suitable for application configuration (as opposed to support data) because they cannot be manipulated in Apex as Settings can - there's currently no support for deleting them from Apex, and Create/Update workflows are much clunkier.